# Compare two mongo ObjectId to check which of two object was created later

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid, objectid

I know that mongo ObjectId has timestamp and random incrementer. So it should be possible to compare two ObjectIds to find out which of these two object was created earlier or later.

How can i do that without writing everything from very scratch?

Comment: The [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation operator can convert the `ObjectId` to a `date` type. The resulting date values can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider a collection `t1` with two documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1705d9bc058dac23306dd0") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1705ddbc058dac23306dd2") }
```

The comparison queries using the `find` method and the Aggregation query using an `ObjectId` to compare with:

```
var INPUT_OBJ = ObjectId("5e1705dcbc058dac23306dd1")

db.t1.aggregate( [
  { $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ { $toDate: "$_id" },  { $toDate: INPUT_OBJ } ] } } }
] )

db.t1.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ { $toDate: "$_id" },  { $toDate: INPUT_OBJ } ] } } )
```

Both the queries return the document: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1705ddbc058dac23306dd2") }`

For verification, the `getTimestamp()` method can be used to get the date/time from the `ObjectId`. For example, `ObjectId("5e1705d9bc058dac23306dd0").getTimestamp()` returns `ISODate("2020-01-09T10:52:09Z")`.